# visibility not appear in my java code

Tags: java

I m reading the "java concurrency in practice". When I read the code:

```
  public class NoVisibility
{
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println(ready+"\t"+number);
            while (!ready)
            {
                Thread.yield();
            }
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        new ReaderThread( ).start();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        number = 42;
        ready =true;


    }
}
```

in the book, it says the loop will endless,but when i run it in java8,the result as this:

```
false   0
42
```

why does it not show visibility problem?

Answer (score 2):

The thread that is initialized with the lambda expression will start looping immediately. You could see that by putting a print statement into that first while loop.

Then, about 1 second later, the other thread that created that first thread changes the value of *ready*. As soon as this change becomes effective, that first while loop with *!ready* will stop.

You either made a mistake when creating your example, or that book is wrong. In other words: *ready* is *visible* two both threads; there is nothing in this code which would explain your expectations.